# How to Use Variable in PHP With Find Option

Tags: php

While Creating Script -

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
    if(isset($_POST['sub']))
                    {

                        $a=$_POST['url'];
                        $customid=$_POST['customids'];
                        $html = file_get_html($a);
                        $displaybody = $html->find('div[id=content]', 0)->plaintext;
                        $display = $html->find('div[class=entry-content]', 0)->plaintext;
                        $customway= $html->find('div[class=pagelist]', 0)->plaintext;
                    }

?>
```

I Want to use Custom Variable, In Addition to Pagelist. For Example i want to use like -

```
$customway= $html->find('div[class=<?php $customid ?>]', 0)->plaintext;
```

also tried

```
$customway= $html->find('div[class=.$customid]', 0)->plaintext;
```

Still no Hopes..

But the Problem Is, There is Mistake in above line, So can anyone tell me the proper way to do this?

HTML Code -

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Scrape Article </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post">
    <tr>
        URL:<td><input type="text" name="url"></td>
        Custom ID:<td><input type="text" name="customids"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="sub" value="Go"></td>
        </tr><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <tr>
         <textarea rows="4" cols="50"><?php echo $displaybody,$display,$customway  ; ?></textarea> 
         </tr>
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's Basically a content scraper from entry URL. So i want to make is work with custom IDS defined, so it can work with any webpage cause different sites use different IDS for content..
Waiting for reply..

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php - note the difference between single and double quotes.

Comment: can you please correct above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$customway= $html->find('div[class='.$customid.']', 0)->plaintext;
```

Comment: I am sure it should work unless $_POST['customids'] is not empty.

Comment: My bad, I was making some other mistakes too. So Finally Your Code worked. Thanks A Ton.

Comment: Cheers happy coding.